# Can't Import React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

## Can't Import React

When I try to import react it throws me an error saying that react is invaldid an "unexpected identifier"

```
#############################################################################
//index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>

#############################################################################
//index.js

import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"

    ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello World</h1>, document.getElementById("root"));

#############################################################################


ERROR: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Comment: Change your js file to jsx and change the script tag to <script type="text/babel" src="index.jsx"></script>

Answer (score 1):

Browser won't understand `import` statements, you have to transpile code using [babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/) and bundle using [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/). Also please try to use react starter kits e.g. [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) which are configured using babel and webpack